# Rewrite rule for .htaccess in php

Tags: php

How to change htaccess from

```
product_details?id=ic3500a192c
```

to

```
product_details/ic3500a192c
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^product_details/ic3500a192c/?  product_details?id=ic3500a192c    [NC,L]  # Handle product requests
```

Comment: Wrong way around, string with id= should be the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this thing.

```
  RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
  RewriteRule ^product_details/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+) product_details/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution how to accomplish this problem:

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^product_details/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    product_details/index.php?id=$1  [NC,L]
```

Comment: @kishanprasad Do you have set `AllowOveride All` in your Apache settings?

Comment: can you help me with this where can i find

Comment: RewriteRule ^product_details/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+) product_details/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this thing.

```
  RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
  RewriteRule ^product_details/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+) product_details/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: @kishanprasad I suspect your file is `product_details/index.php`, or similar right? If so, then that needs to be specified in the rewrite, since L indicates this will be the last rule applied, so the webserver won't automatically go to the index file.

Comment: please tell me your file name.

Comment: world of control

Comment: http://localhost/worldofcontrol/product_details?id=ic3500a192c i need to change it to http://localhost/worldofcontrol/product_details/ic3500a192c and id values are from database so it chnages.

Comment: RewriteRule ^product_details/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+) product_details/index.php?id=$1

Comment: please try above rules

Comment: then please true or correct my answer and up vote my answer.